# Jadira Month incorrect

Tags: date, jodatime

I have a DateOperations class which is as such.

```
public static Date formatInputToDate(String input,String pattern){
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(input, DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern));
    return new Date(localDateTime.toDate().getTime());
}
```

and I am getting returned date format as "14-32-18 06:32:00" when i do a toString("yy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") on the LocalDateTime class after getting constructed from the above method.Please tell me the error.
the input is 11/18/2014 and pattern is mm/dd/yy

thanks,

Comment: Yes i got the answer.. If we change the pattern "mm" to "MM" then it works fine. My mistake. Thanks for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**m** stands for *minute of hour*, **M** for *month of year*. Please first study the [javadoc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) which format symbols Joda-Time uses.